# Планировщик заданий для приложения на django/postgresql

Tags: postgresql, django

Добрый день.

Возникла необходимость настроить переодическое выполнение определённой задачи (обновление данных в БД) в приложении, написанном на стеке django/postgresql.

Проблема в том, что требуется не привязываться к платформе, поэтому варианты типа cron'a отпадают. И, к сожалению, postgresql не имеет аналога job'ов, как в Oracle.

Есть ли какие-либо варианты реализации данного функционала? Возможно, средствами django.

Answer (score 2):

[celery](http://www.celeryproject.org/), [django-rq](https://github.com/ui/django-rq) могут выполнять задачи по расписанию. Все они требуют установки дополнительного ПО (RabbitMQ, Redis)

Я бы не стал отметать cron, даже если вы решите использовать какой-то из этих планировщиков.
Ведь вам достаточно написать management-команду и заставить ее выполнять вашу переодическую задачу. И пользователь сам сможет запустить ее через cron, windows scheduler или что ему будет угодно.

Answer (score 1):

Насколько помню, раньше [celery](http://www.celeryproject.org/) позволял организовать выполнение задач по расписанию с контролем через админку. Посмотрите, может, и сейчас можно, давно туда не заглядывал.